# Populate unique values into a VBA array from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone give me VBA code that will take a range (row or column) from an Excel sheet and populate a list/array with the unique values, 
i.e.:

```
table
table
chair
table
stool
stool
stool
chair
```

when the macro runs would create an array some thing like:

```
fur[0]=table
fur[1]=chair
fur[2]=stool
```

Comment: are we talking about VB or VBA? (VB -> an external program reading the excel file or using interop to control excel; VBA -> VB for Applications ... see excel macro editor)

Comment: well i did say macros in my post, but yes sorry VBA

Comment: if you are refering to VBA, try this: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/identifying_unique_values_in_an_array_or_range/

Comment: You should post your edit as a new question, otherwise it won't get addressed.

Comment: Hi, i did do, then I relised what a fool I was bing of say the error of my ways :) Thanks for the hep by the way its been great.

Comment: I guess you could pivot over it entirely without a macro

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this situation I always use code like this (just make sure delimeter you've chosen is not a part of search range)

```
Dim tmp As String
Dim arr() As String

If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
   For Each cell In Selection
      If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp, cell) = 0) Then
        tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
      End If
   Next cell
End If

If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)

arr = Split(tmp, "|")
```

Comment: But what does it do with "footstool" followed by "stool" ?  Maybe you should try that first...

Comment: well it happly takes a list that included the following strings ASR Port Provisioning, ASR Port Provisioning General Questions, ASR Port Provisioning No Actions, And pop[ulates the array as them being unique

Comment: Indeed, it will not work OK in some cases like "footstool" followed by "stool". In some situations it's not a problem, if it's - you can eaisly adapt the code, by looking not the word "stool", but word between delimiters from: "|stool|". Of course, your tmp string must begin with delimiter also and it must be cut before transform into array. To summarize: you concat in temporary string like |table|chair|stool|footstool|, and use InStr function to look for word with delimiters, like |stool|

Comment: Except if the first element is "stool", in which case it won't have a delimiter on both sides and `InStr` won't find it. To prevent this, initialise `tmp` like this: `tmp="|"`. Anyway, this feels like a dirty novelty hack to me! Why not do it the proper way?!

Comment: In programing / Scripings there is no "proper" way, simple better and worse ways ;)

Comment: Unless the source range is very small (<100 cells) I would assign the values to an array first rather than individually examining each cell in the range, especially if the process is time critical (e.g. populating the filtered values into a combobox etc.)

Answer (score 33):

```
Sub GetUniqueAndCount()

    Dim d As Object, c As Range, k, tmp As String

    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In Selection
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1
    Next c

    For Each k In d.keys
        Debug.Print k, d(k)
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm interested in this answer but when I try to implement it I get a runtime error 429 `ActiveX component can't create object`. Clicking on the debug button takes me to the line `Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")` . any ideas on how to get past this error?

Comment: Are you on a Mac?  If Yes that will not work since the Scripting runtime is a Windows-only thing.  There is a drop-in replacement for Scripting.Dictionary available here though: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary

Answer (score 11):

Combining the Dictionary approach from Tim with the variant array from  Jean_Francois below.

The array you want is in `objDict.keys`

[image]

```
Sub A_Unique_B()
Dim X
Dim objDict As Object
Dim lngRow As Long

Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
X = Application.Transpose(Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))

For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    objDict(X(lngRow)) = 1
Next
Range("B1:B" & objDict.Count) = Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

**Profiting from the MS Excel 365 function `UNIQUE()`**

In order to enrich the valid solutions above:

```
Sub ExampleCall()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A11")   ' << change to your sheet's Code(Name)
Dim a: a = rng
a = getUniques(a)
arrInfo a
End Sub
```

```
Function getUniques(a, Optional ZeroBased As Boolean = True)
Dim tmp: tmp = Application.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Unique(a))
If ZeroBased Then ReDim Preserve tmp(0 To UBound(tmp) - 1)
getUniques = tmp
End Function
```

Comment: [Inspired](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59683363/9758194) =) ?

Comment: @JvdV - *inspired* above all by [Support UNIQUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), and yes I knew the cited link *(very impressive & btw upvted/Jan. :-)*. - If you don't want to maintain the original order as in OP, a combination with the new [SORT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c) can add new functionality.

Comment: Yes, AD-functionality opens up a whole new world of possibilities =)

Answer (score 4):

This is the old-school way of doing it.

It will execute faster than looping through cells (e.g. `For Each cell In Selection`) and will be reliable no matter what, as long you have a rectangular selection (i.e. not Ctrl-selecting a bunch of random cells).

```
Sub FindUnique()

    Dim varIn As Variant
    Dim varUnique As Variant
    Dim iInCol As Long
    Dim iInRow As Long
    Dim iUnique As Long
    Dim nUnique As Long
    Dim isUnique As Boolean

    varIn = Selection
    ReDim varUnique(1 To UBound(varIn, 1) * UBound(varIn, 2))

    nUnique = 0
    For iInRow = LBound(varIn, 1) To UBound(varIn, 1)
        For iInCol = LBound(varIn, 2) To UBound(varIn, 2)

            isUnique = True
            For iUnique = 1 To nUnique
                If varIn(iInRow, iInCol) = varUnique(iUnique) Then
                    isUnique = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next iUnique

            If isUnique = True Then
                nUnique = nUnique + 1
                varUnique(nUnique) = varIn(iInRow, iInCol)
            End If

        Next iInCol
    Next iInRow
    '// varUnique now contains only the unique values. 
    '// Trim off the empty elements:
    ReDim Preserve varUnique(1 To nUnique)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

OK I did it finally:

```
Sub CountUniqueRecords()
Dim Array() as variant, UniqueArray() as variant, UniqueNo as Integer,      
Dim i as integer, j as integer, k as integer

Redim UnquiArray(1)

k= Upbound(array)

For i = 1 To k
For j = 1 To UniqueNo + 1
  If Array(i) = UniqueArray(j) Then GoTo Nx
Next j
  UniqueNo = UniqueNo + 1
  ReDim Preserve UniqueArray(UniqueNo + 1)
  UniqueArray(UniqueNo) = Array(i)
Nx:
Next i

MsgBox UniqueNo

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

one more way ...

```
Sub get_unique()
Dim unique_string As String
    lr = Sheets("data").Cells(Sheets("data").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set range1 = Sheets("data").Range("A2:A" & lr)
    For Each cel In range1
       If Not InStr(output, cel.Value) > 0 Then
           unique_string = unique_string & cel.Value & ","
       End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: To be corrected : `If Not InStr(unique_string, cel.Value) > 0 Then`

Answer (score 1):

This VBA function returns an array of distinct values when passed either a range or a 2D array source

It defaults to processing the first column of the source, but you can optionally choose another column.

I wrote a [LinkedIn article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/excel-vba-get-unique-values-easily-daniel-ferry/) about it.

```
Function DistinctVals(a, Optional col = 1)
    Dim i&, v: v = a
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 1 To UBound(v): .Item(v(i, col)) = 1: Next
        DistinctVals = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Classic approach & quick; close to Brettdj's solution :+) - FYI you might be interested in my solution profiting from the MS Excel 365 `UNIQUE()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The old school method was my favourite option. Thank you. And it was indeed fast.  But I didn't use redim.  Here though is my real world example where I accumulate values for each unique "key" found in a column and move it into a array (say for an employee and values are hours worked per day). Then I put each key with its final values into a totals area on the active sheet. I've commented extensively for anyone who wants painful detail on what is happening here.  Limited error checking is done by this code.

```
Sub GetActualTotals()
'
' GetActualTotals Macro
'
' This macro accumulates values for each unique employee from the active
' spreadsheet.
'
' History
' October 2016 - Version 1
'
' Invocation
' I created a button labeled "Get Totals" on the Active Sheet that invokes
' this macro.
'
Dim ResourceName As String
Dim TotalHours As Double
Dim TotalPercent As Double
Dim IsUnique As Boolean
Dim FirstRow, LastRow, LastColumn, LastResource, nUnique As Long
Dim CurResource, CurrentRow, i, j As Integer
Dim Resource(1000, 2) As Variant
Dim Rng, r As Range
'
' INITIALIZATIONS
'
' These are index numbers for the Resource array
'
Const RName = 0
Const TotHours = 1
Const TotPercent = 2
'
' Set the maximum number of resources we'll
' process.
'
Const ResourceLimit = 1000
'
' We are counting on there being no unintended data
' in the spreadsheet.
'
' It won't matter if the cells are empty though. It just
' may take longer to run the macro.
' But if there is data where this macro does not expect it,
' assume unpredictable results.
'
' There are some hardcoded values used.
' This macro just happens to expect the names to be in Column C (or 3).
'
' Get the last row in the spreadsheet:
'
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("C1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
'
'  Furthermore, this macro banks on the first actual name to be in C6.
'  so if the last row is row 65, the range we'll work with 
'  will evaluate to "C6:C65"
'
FirstRow = 6
Rng = "C" & FirstRow & ":C" & LastRow
Set r = Range(Rng)
'
' Initialize the resource array to be empty (even though we don't really
' need to but I'm old school).  
'
For CurResource = 0 To ResourceLimit
    Resource(CurResource, RName) = ""
    Resource(CurResource, TotHours) = 0
    Resource(CurResource, TotPercent) = 0
Next CurResource
'
' Start the resource counter at 0.  The counter will represent the number of
' unique entries. 
'
 nUnique = 0
'
' LET'S GO
'
' Loop from the first relative row and the last relative row
' to process all the cells in the spreadsheet we are interested in
'
For i = 1 To LastRow - FirstRow
'
' Loop here for all unique entries. For any
' new unique entry, that array element will be
' initialized in the second if statement.
'
    IsUnique = True
    For j = 1 To nUnique
'
' If the current row element has a resource name and is already
' in the resource array, then accumulate the totals for that
' Resource Name. We then have to set IsUnique to false and
' exit the for loop to make sure we don't populate
' a new array element in the next if statement.
'
        If r.Cells(i, 1).Value = Resource(j, RName) Then
            IsUnique = False
            Resource(j, TotHours) = Resource(j, TotHours) + _
            r.Cells(i, 4).Value
            Resource(j, TotPercent) = Resource(j, TotPercent) + _
            r.Cells(i,5).Value
            Exit For
        End If
     Next j
'
' If the resource name is unique then copy the initial
' values we find into the next resource array element.
' I ignore any null cells.   (If the cell has a blank you might
' want to add a Trim to the cell).   Not much error checking for 
' the numerical values either.
'
    If ((IsUnique) And (r.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "")) Then
        nUnique = nUnique + 1
        Resource(nUnique, RName) = r.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Resource(nUnique, TotHours) = Resource(nUnique, TotHours) + _ 
        r.Cells(i, 4).Value
        Resource(nUnique, TotPercent) = Resource(nUnique, TotPercent) + _
        r.Cells(i, 5).Value
    End If                  
Next i
'
' Done processing all rows
'
' (For readability) Set the last resource counter to the last value of
' nUnique.
' Set the current row to the first relative row in the range (r=the range).
'
LastResource = nUnique
CurrentRow = 1
'
' Populate the destination cells with the accumulated values for
' each unique resource name.
'
For CurResource = 1 To LastResource
    r.Cells(CurrentRow, 7).Value = Resource(CurResource, RName)
    r.Cells(CurrentRow, 8).Value = Resource(CurResource, TotHours)
    r.Cells(CurrentRow, 9).Value = Resource(CurResource, TotPercent)
    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
Next CurResource

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The VBA script below looks for all unique values from cell B5 all the way down to the very last cell in column B… $B$1048576. Once it is found, they are stored in the array (objDict).

```
Private Const SHT_MASTER = “MASTER”
Private Const SHT_INST_INDEX = “InstrumentIndex”

Sub UniqueList()
    Dim Xyber
    Dim objDict As Object
    Dim lngRow As Long

    Sheets(SHT_MASTER).Activate
    Xyber = Application.Transpose(Sheets(SHT_MASTER).Range([b5], Cells(Rows.count, “B”).End(xlUp)))
    Sheets(SHT_INST_INDEX).Activate
    Set objDict = CreateObject(“Scripting.Dictionary”)
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(Xyber, 1)
    If Len(Xyber(lngRow)) > 0 Then objDict(Xyber(lngRow)) = 1
    Next
    Sheets(SHT_INST_INDEX).Range(“B1:B” & objDict.count) = Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)
End Sub
```

I have tested and documented with some screenshots of the this solution. Here is the link where you can find it....

http://xybernetics.com/techtalk/excelvba-getarrayofuniquevaluesfromspecificcolumn/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the Variant data type, then you can use the in-built worksheet function *Unique* as shown.

```
sub unique_results_to_array()
    dim rng_data as Range
    set rng_data = activesheet.range("A1:A10") 'enter the range of data here

    dim my_arr() as Variant
    my_arr = WorksheetFunction.Unique(rng_data)
    
    first_val  = my_arr(1,1)
    second_val = my_arr(2,1)
    third_val = my_arr(3,1)   'etc...    

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in the count function, then you could simplify the dictionary approach by using empty quotes for the dictionary value instead of the counter.  The following code assumes the first cell containing data is "A1". Alternatively, you could use the Selection (though I understand that is generally frowned upon) or the sheet's UsedRange attribute as your range.

Both of the following examples assume that you want to omit blank values from your array of unique values.

Note that to utilize dictionary objects as follows, you must have the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library active in your references. Also note that by declaring dict as a New Dictionary instead of a Dictionary in the beginning, you can forgo the step of setting it equal to a Scripting Dictionary later. Also, dictionary keys must be unique, and this method does not result in errors when setting the value corresponding to a given dictionary key, so there is no risk of having unique keys.

```
Sub GetUniqueValuesInRange()

    Dim cll     As Range
    Dim rng     As Range
    Dim dict    As New Dictionary
    Dim vArray  As Variant
    
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1)
    
    For Each cll In rng.Cells
        If Len(cll.Value) > 0 Then
            dict(cll.Value) = ""
        End If
    Next cll
    
    vArray = dict.Keys
    
End Sub
```

The prior example is a slower method, as it is generally preferred to move the values into an array in the beginning, so that all calculations can be performed in the memory.  The following should work faster for larger data sets:

```
Sub GetUniqueValuesInRange2()

    Dim vFullArray      As Variant
    Dim var             As Variant
    Dim dict            As New Dictionary
    Dim vUniqueArray    As Variant
    
    vFullArray = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Value
    
    For Each var In vFullArray
        If Len(var) > 0 Then
            dict(var) = ""
        End If
    Next var
    
    vUniqueArray = dict.Keys
    
End Sub
```