# Easiest Way to Find and Remove Duplicates?

Tags: vba, duplicates

I have two columns filled with data in an Excel spreadsheet:

```
Column 1:
A
B
C
D

Column 2:
C
D
E
F
G

Desired Data: A,B,C,D,E,F,G (not A,B,C,D,C,D,E,F,G)
```

I want to combine the two columns, and remove any duplicates.  I'm coming from a C# word, so my understanding of VBA is limited.  I know I could create an array with the dimension of dimension(column1)+dimension(column2), then do some duplicate removal (is there one built in?), or something like that.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890257/populate-unique-values-in-to-vba-array-from-excel/5891317#5891317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following to do the processing...and just call it as you would any other function or subroutine.

```
Sub RemoveDupes()

    'Add extra Column, "A" becomes "B"
    Columns(1).EntireColumn.Insert

    'Filter out duplicates and copy unique list to "A"
    Range("B1", Range("B65536").End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("A1"), Unique:=True

    'Add extra Column, "B" becomes "A"
    Columns(2).EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Then just join and sort the results from each column :)

Comment: If you remove the dupes in each then join, you would have to remove dupes again.  or you could just remove dupes once after joining them. just sayin' :)