# calculate the sum of 2 column values in a 3rd column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Populate unique values in to VBA array from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890257/populate-unique-values-in-to-vba-array-from-excel)

I need to calculate the sum of 2 (A&B) columns value in a 3rd (C) Column. But I don't want to write the `=B1+C1` in every column.

Is there any formula to calculate the sum of each row values of A & B column automatically into C column?

Comment: You can =b1+a1 in c1 and drag it down ColC. I'm unclear as to what you're trying to avoid doing?

Comment: see my answer... if that is not case please update your question with input and output...

Comment: please give some more context: there are two solutions suggested below, and not a word from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is right, and when you copy that content to every cell in column b, the numbers will adapted, so the sum to the row is calculated. That magic happens while you copy the contents of one cell to another cell. This is possible because the addressing of cells is by default relative to the cell with the formula.

You even have to write "=B$1+C$1" to fix the row to "1".

So, under the hood, all these formulas are the same and what you want.