# Excel VB script find duplicate values in A and copy row with the smallest value in B

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet where values are in the column A and B. Column A has duplicate values. I need to find the smallest value in column B for a given value in column A, and copy that value into a new column. How can I do this?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXCoV.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate unique values into a VBA array from Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890257/populate-unique-values-into-a-vba-array-from-excel) among many others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in VBA, you could use a `Scripting.Dictionary`, with each iteration checking if the new value is less than the previous value for a given key.

Then, since the keys and values are exposed on the Dictionary as arrays, you can simply write the keys/values to a destination range.

---

Alternatively, you could issue the following SQL statement against the Excel worksheet:

```
SELECT Field1, MIN(Field2)
FROM [$Sheet1]
GROUP BY Field1
```

Presumably you would do this via an ADO or DAO Recordset, which you can paste into the destination range using the `CopyFromRecordset` method.