# Create list of unique values from a range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, array-formulas

I have data (names) spread out in a sheet in Excel. It is in columns A through M.
Some rows have data in every column (A-M), some rows have nothing.

I want to extract a list of every unique value (or even a list of every value, and then I can remove duplicates) in the range.

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to do this and haven't found an example online that pulls unique values from a RANGE, and not a single column.

Any ideas? Let me know if you need a screenshot of the data for more context.

Comment: Are you open to a VBA solution?

Comment: If it isn't too hard to figure out, sure! I have a little bit of VBA experience.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890257/populate-unique-values-into-a-vba-array-from-excel/5891317#5891317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this macro a try:

```
Sub MAINevent()
    Dim it As Range, r As Range, x0
        With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
            For Each it In Range("A:M").SpecialCells(2)
                x0 = .Item(it.Value)
            Next

            Set r = Cells(1, "N").Resize(.Count, 1)
            r.Value = Application.Transpose(.Keys)
        End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Go to Special` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> -> `Special`) to select `blanks` and remove them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> with cells selected). Then use the formula described [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4233-excel-stack-columns.html#a3) to stack all your columns in one, on top of each other. Then replace formulas with values and finally, use `Remove Duplicates`.